# Get Stream io Not able to update feed activities

Tags: java, feed, getstream-io

I am using getstream io for feed.when I tried to update the stream It show error

```
AuthenticationFailedException{statusCode=403, code=0, exception=PermissionDenied, detail=You do not have permission to perform this action.}
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.handlers.StreamExceptionHandler.handleResponseCode(StreamExceptionHandler.java:76)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamActivityRepository.handleResponseCode(StreamActivityRepository.java:273)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamActivityRepository.updateActivities(StreamActivityRepository.java:267)
    at io.getstream.client.okhttp.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.updateActivities(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:214)
    at io.getstream.client.service.AbstractActivityService.updateActivities(AbstractActivityService.java:97)
```

I code is

```
StreamActivitiesResponse<PostForStream> response = flatActivityServiceForPost.updateActivities(postStream);

            response.getActivities();
```

where postStream is List .

how I can update the feed item.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 response means you weren't authenticated to our system properly, or the API key/secret you used wasn't allowed to access the feed you're trying to update. There's also a possibility that your application didn't create the authentication header properly with a JSON Web Token (JWT) to push an update.

If you're using the real-time notification system, and passing a auth token to a browser for a feed to connect to Stream, that connection is read-only per our docs, so even if you're building a JWT for the payload, trying to push data to Stream using that auth token.

If, however, this is on the back end, we'd need to see more about how you're connecting to our systems. Feel free to send a quick email to our support team and I can help you further there.